# Why doesnt this code work recursive function gets an error

Tags: ocaml

I am supposed to check if two lists are anagrams I think I made the proper code for that task but this need help

```
let rec ana l1 l2 = 
    if l1=[] && l2=[] then true
    else if List.hd l1 = List.hd l2 then  ana (List.tl l1) l2
    else if  List.hd l1 != List.hd l2 then ana l1 (List.tl l2)
    else false;; 

  ana [2;9;4;7] [2;4;7;9];;
```

Comment: Hey it doesnt mater, welcome to SO! This doesn't answer your question, but I advise you do not use != for inequality. It may work on integers (on accident) but will have very quirky behaviors on other values. The proper inequality operator is `<>`.

Comment: And since we might not have access to an OCaml environemnt and aren't all mindreaders, you might also want to include the actual error message. Help us help you and all that, you know?

Comment: Exception faliure "hd"

Answer (score 1):

You're not handling the case where one or the other list is empty, only when both are. Therefore, when you get to `else if List.hd l1 = List.hd l2`, when either `l1` or `l2` is empty, `List.hd` will raise an exception because it is not defined for empty lists.

You might want to use pattern matching instead, which would have avoided this and warned you about any missing cases. Here's your code rewritten using pattern matching. It still doesn't do what you want, but it doesn't raise an exception at least:

```
let rec ana l1 l2 =
  match l1, l2 with
  | [], [] ->
    true

  | h1::t1, h2::t2 ->
    if h1 = h2 then
      ana t1 l2
    else
      ana l1 t2

  | _ ->
    false
```